# Obtener las keys de un array obtenido por API en JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Estoy consumiento una api y al momento de trear el  los objetos , me los trae como undefined
usando un ajax quiero que me muestre los nombres de esos arreglos

```
    $.ajax({
        
        'url':"https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all",
        'type':'GET',
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            
            console.log(response.message)
                                       
                 let todaslasrazas='';
                $.each(response.message,function(index,value){     
                    
                    todaslasrazas+="<li>"+value.message+"</li>";
            })     
            $("#listarazas").html(todaslasrazas)
        }
    })
   }
```

mi html es cual quiero que muestre los nombres posteriormente en un combo box

```
    <ul id="listarazas">
        <li>Razas</li>
        <li> <div id="listarazas"></div></li>
    
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer argumento del callback del `$.each` no es `index`, es el `key`, porque lo que estás recorriendo es un objeto. Ese `key` es el que contiene las razas. Usa ese valor para tus `li`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes testear acá:

```js
$.ajax({
    'url': "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all",
    'type': 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var todaslasrazas = "";
        $.each(response.message, function (key, value) {
            todaslasrazas += "<li>" + key + "</li>";
        })
        $("#listarazas").html(todaslasrazas)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Razas</h1>
<ul id="listarazas"></ul>
```

No sé exactamente el tipo de combo box que planeas usar, pero acá te dejo un ejemplo con un `select` nativo de javascript:

```js
$.ajax({
    'url': "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all",
    'type': 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var todaslasrazas = "";
        $.each(response.message, function (key, value) {
            todaslasrazas += `<option value="${key}">${key}</option>`;
        })
        $("#listarazas").html(todaslasrazas)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="listarazas"> Seleccione la raza: </label>
<select id="listarazas"></select>
```

Comment: gracias amigo me funcione impecable ahora podre seguir con el ejercicio (y)